# XAML, Image control, local storage image

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

The first is the first, I'm very newbie on .NET, I was developed un Visual Basic 6, but now I'm trying to make an application to Windows Phone 8.0.

At this time I'm trapped with a (maybe simple) problem.

I have a xaml page with  control, and it is part of LongListSelector thats implements an Observable Collection of "Prenda" class.

```
        ...
        var prendasData = from r in db.Prendas select r;
        PrendasItems = new ObservableCollection<Prenda>(prendasData);
        llsPrendas.ItemsSource = PrendasItems;
        ...
```

The XAML portion is the code bellow, please, i know that severals things maybe are wrong, but I'm learning alone, be patient with me :D

```
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="llsPrendas" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Prendas}" SelectionChanged="llsPrendasSelectionChanged">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Width="100" Height="100" Margin="5,0,0,0" Source="{Binding PrendaImageURI}" ImageFailed="errcargaimg"/>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Normal"  Text="{Binding Nombre}" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Normal"  Text="{Binding Precio}" Margin="10,0,0,0" />                                
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

The problem is the Image Control. It doesn't show anything and if I debug it, the error the message is: "AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR", googled this error and I know that is (in this case) same as "File not found." But I'm sure thats file exists. because I seen it with IsoStoreSpy, at /Shared/Media/ShellContent/WP_XXX.jpg, i think that the root of the Isolated Storage is called isostore:/ and the complete URI must be: isostore:/Shared/Media/ShellContent/WP_XXX.jpg.

This string is saved as string column in the class, and I create a property thats use this string to make an Uri to use to bind the Source property of Image control at design time.

(portion of class declaration)

```
            [Column]
            public string Foto 
            {
                get 
                { 
                    return foto; 
                }
                set 
                {
                    if (foto != value)
                    {
                        foto = value;
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("Foto");
                    }
                }
            }
            public Uri PrendaImageURI
            {
                get
                {
                    return new Uri(this.Foto, UriKind.Absolute);
                }
            }
```

I'm going crazy, because I cannot understand why it's doesn't work. Can somebody help me? (Sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not read from Isolated storage using URI, You have to read using IsolatedStorageFile class:

```
private static BitmapImage GetImageFromIsolatedStorage(string imageName)
{
    var bimg = new BitmapImage();
    using (var iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (var stream = iso.OpenFile(imageName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            bimg.SetSource(stream);
        }
    }
    return bimg;
}
```

You can find more details from below Posts:

[How get image from isolated storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900315/how-get-image-from-isolated-storage)

[How to load an image from isolated storage into image control on windows phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914464/how-to-load-an-image-from-isolated-storage-into-image-control-on-windows-phone)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with Pratik Goyal help (thank you, very much!), making a BitmapImage Property in the class "Prendas", taking The Foto string data. Later I will take more careful with the exception control, but is a good start, I think.

```
    public BitmapImage ImageFoto
    {
        get
        {
            return GetImageFromIsolatedStorage(Foto);
        }

    }
    public BitmapImage GetImageFromIsolatedStorage(string imageName)
    {

        var bimg = new BitmapImage();
        using (var iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (var stream = iso.OpenFile(imageName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                bimg.SetSource(stream);
            }
        }
        return bimg;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the children:

Silverlight notifies this with an AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR / HRESULT=0x80131500. Which of course can't be found anywhere on the web and of course means jack and shit to me and not only to me.

Answer (score -2):

Is the UI being notified of the PrendaImageURI property changing?

Try adding

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("PrendaImageURI");
```

when your Foto property is set.